# Smooth frame animating on UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to move a UIView around the screen by incrementing the UIView's x property in an animation block. I want the element to move continuously so I cannot just specify an ending x and up the duration.

This code works but it is very choppy. Looks great in the simulator but choppy on the device.

```
-(void)moveGreyDocumentRight:(UIImageView*)greyFolderView
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.05 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
    NSInteger newX = greyFolderView.frame.origin.x + 5.0;
    greyFolderView.frame = CGRectMake(newX, greyFolderView.frame.origin.y, greyFolderView.frame.size.width, greyFolderView.frame.size.height);
    }
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self moveGreyDocumentRight:greyFolderView];
}];
```

}

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690141/how-to-do-a-continuous-recycling-uiview-animation

Comment: If you're just moving back and forth between two locations, the combination of `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` and `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` for a standard `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` block animation will do the job. Combine it with `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut` and the "turning around" process will be smooth, too. If you want to do something else (e.g. not between two locations) let us know and we can suggest other alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're fighting the view animation here. Each one of your animations includes a `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut` timing curve. That means that every 0.05 seconds you try to ramp up your speed then slow down your speed then change to somewhere else.

The first and simplest solution is likely to change to a linear timing by passing the option `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear`.

That said, making a new animation every 5ms really fights the point of Core Animation, complicating the code and hurting performance. Send the frame it to the place you *currently* want it to go. Whenever you want it to go somewhere else (even if it's still animating), send it to the new place passing the option `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState`. It will automatically adjust to the new target. If you want it to repeat the animation or bounce back and forth, use the repeating options (`UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` and `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse`).

Comment: this was exactly the solution. Animating every 0.05 seconds was not an issue at all. Very smooth and sexy :)